# Iterate through an Ruby Array and get(yield or return) each item in the array

Tags: ruby

I have an array and I need to create a class method named "each" to yield or return (not sure what the difference is of those or which I need to use if any) each item in the array when the method is called.

Do I need to use return instead of yield or neither?

```
class Sum

 def initialize
   @sum =  Array.new
 end

 def each
 @sum.each do |item|
   yield item
 end 

end
```

Comment: I assume this is homework?

Comment: Other than a missing `end`, your code as written works. What is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could include `Enumerable` and implement `each` and get a lot of functionality for free.

```
class Sum
  def initialize
    @sum = []
  end

  def each &block
    @sum.each &block
  end
end
```

This will `yield` each item of the collection or if you do not provide a block it will return you an enumerator just like a normal `Array` would

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to write a class that acts like an iterator?  That provides it's own `each` form?  If so, then this is the pattern for doing so with a ruby class:

```
class MyIterator
  include Enumerable

  def initialize data=[]
    @data = data
  end 

  def each
    @data.each do |item|
      yield item
    end 
  end 
end

m = MyIterator.new [1,2,3,4]

m.each do |item|
  puts "item=#{item}"
end

puts m.map(&:next)
```

The `for_each` method iterates over the array (`@data`) and yields each of the values to the block.

As @jan-dvorak pointed out, including `Enumerable` and naming the method `each` gives additional benefits, such as being able to call `map` directly on the object.

Comment: Why not name the method `each`? And `include Enumerable`, for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is homework, and using the existing `each` method is not allowed:

```
class Sum
  def initialize
    @values = []
  end
  def homework_each
    0.upto(@values.length-1){ |i| yield @values[i] }
  end
end
```

However, your code as written works, modulo the fact that you're missing an `end`, and also you're missing any way to populate your array with values.