# Converting Ruby loop iteration with a yield statement to Python

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying to teach myself Python by translating the code in the Mazes for Programmers book from Jamis Buck. It's a great book but it's written in Ruby and I'm getting stuck on understanding some of the Ruby code.

To understand the problem, I've included a reduced version of the codebase

**cell.rb**

```
class Cell
  attr_reader : row, :column

def initialize(row, column)
  @row, @column = row, column
end
```

**grid.rb**

```
require 'cell'
class Grid
  attr_reader :rows, :columns

def initialize(rows, columns)
  @rows = rows
  @columns = columns
  @grid = prepare_grid
end

def prepare_grid
  Array.new(rows) do |row|
    Array.new(columns) do |column|
      Cell.new(row, column)
    end
  end
end
```

So far so good. All of the above is easy to understand and translate to Python. Then there are the following two functions as part of the Grid class.

```
def each_row
  @grid.each do |row|
    yield row
  end
end

def each_cell
  each_row do |row|
    row.each do |cell|
      yield cell if cell
    end
  end
end
```

What are the last two functions here actually doing? I've found something similar [here](http://thisishardtoread.com/2013/12/12/mimicking-ruby-yield-in-python.html) that leads me to think that the Python version will need to accept an optional lambda variable, test to see that it's not null, and if it isn't then run the code associated with the variable. The problem is that I know the intent of these functions is to be an iterator and I don't think that adding in a lambda will help.

There is a somewhat similar question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801697/iterate-through-an-ruby-array-and-getyield-or-return-each-item-in-the-array) on StackOverflow which makes me think that the answer is trivial, but I don't know enough about Ruby to be able to intuit the answer or ask Google the right questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then there are the following two functions as part of the Grid class.

These aren't functions. They are methods.

> ```
> def each_row
>   @grid.each do |row|
>     yield row
>   end
> end
>
> def each_cell
>   each_row do |row|
>     row.each do |cell|
>       yield cell if cell
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> What are the last two functions here actually doing?

The `each_row` *method* takes a block as parameter and will successively `yield` all elements of the `@grid` array. `@grid` is structured as an array of arrays, representing rows of cells. In other words, `each_row` will successively `yield` each row of the grid, i.e. it is an iterator method for rows.

The `each_cell` *method* takes a block as parameter and will successively `yield` all elements of the row arrays in the grid `@grid` array. In other words, `each_cell` will successively `yield` each cell of the grid if it exists, i.e. it is an iterator method for cells.

The literal translation to Python would be something like this (untested):

```
def each_row(self, f):
  self.grid.each(lambda row: f(row))

def each_cell(self, f):
  self.each_row(lambda row: lambda cell: if cell: f(cell))
```

But, it just doesn't make sense to translate code from one language to another this way. Using lambdas for iteration in Python is non-idiomatic. Python uses iterators for iteration. So, instead of having `each_row` and `each_cell` iterator methods, you would rather have `row_iterator` and `cell_iterator` getters which return iterator objects for the rows and cells, so that you can then do something like:

```
for cell in grid.cell_iterator
```

instead of

```
grid.each_cell(lambda cell: …)
```

Something like this (also untested):

```
def row_iterator(self):
  for row in self.grid: yield row

def cell_iterator(self):
  for row in self.row_iterator:
    for cell in row:
      if cell: yield cell
```

When you "translate" code from one language to another, you cannot just translate it line-by-line, statement-by-statement, expression-by-expression, subroutine-by-subroutine, class-by-class, etc. You need to re-design it from the ground up, using the patterns, practices, and idioms of the community and the types, classes, subroutines, modules, etc. from the language and its core and standard libraries.

Otherwise, you could just use a compiler. A compiler is literally defined as "a program that translates a program from one language to another language". If that is all you want to do, use a compiler. But, if you want the translated code to be readable, understandable, maintainable, and idiomatic, it can only be done by a human.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code, and the intent behind it, so that I can make it function as a well written, well structured piece of Python code. So, thank you for your answer.